# Javascript timer paused when alert box appears

Tags: javascript, html

My program counts how long it takes a user to guess the correct name of each state.

When the user clicks the star where the state is, an input box appears, asking the user to type the name of the state.

When I hit the start button the timer begins, but when I select a star to input the answer, the timer stops.

How can I make the timer continue even after an alert is called?

**My script file**

```
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
var timeId, score;
var count = 0;
states = 50;

startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);

function startTimer() {
    startButton.removeEventListener("click", startTimer);
    timeId = window.setInterval(displayNumber, 1000);

}

function displayNumber() {
    count++;
    messages.innerHTML = count;
    if (count == 10) {
        alert("time's up");
        score = (correctChoice - incorrectChoice) * 2;
        alert("your score is " + correctChoice);
        window.clearInterval(timeId);
    }
}
```

**additional script file**

```
var correctChoice = 0;
var incorrectChoice = 0;

document.getElementById("California").addEventListener("click", choice1);

function choice1(e) {
    if (e.type == "click") {
        input = window.prompt("What is the state");
    }
    if (input != "California") {
        alert("wrong answer");
    } else {
        alert("Correct Answer")
        correctChoice++;
        //comment on parent/child node
        var image1 = document.getElementById('California');
        image1.parentNode.removeChild(image1);
        if (correctChoice == 2) {
            alert("you have guessed them all correctly");
            score = (correctChoice - incorrectChoice) * 2;
            alert("your score is " + correctChoice);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> MEMORY </title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url("usa.jpg");
            background-size: 900px 600px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 10pt">
            <input type="button" value="Start!" id="startButton" style="width:80px" />
            <input type="button" value="Reset" id="resetButton" style="width:80px" onClick="window.location.reload()" />

            <h2 id="messages"> </h2>
        </div>
        <img src="state.png" id="California" value="California" width="30px" height="30px" style="position: absolute; left: 130px; top: 200pt" />
    </body>

    <script src="simonSays.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The modal dialogs don't pause the timers par say, rather Javascript won't stack up timer events triggered by a single timer function call. Why don't you use setTimeout rather than setInterval? If the timer expires while a modal dialog is being prompted - it won't interrupt it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kieran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41204566/1218980) is right in saying that the prompt blocks the execution but **a worker or another thread is overkill** for your simple app.

What you need is to **calculate time difference**. Incrementing a variable isn't reliable as it's more of a number of checks than it is a time count.

```
var startTime = new Date(),
    timeLimit = 10; // in seconds

function getElapsed() {
    return (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
}

function isTimesUp() {
    return getElapsed() >= timeLimit;
}

function promptUser() {
    var input = window.prompt("What is the state");
    // before checking the answer, ensure that there's time left.
    if (isTimesUp()) return timesUp();
    // else check if the answer is correct
}
```

The time for the user to enter an answer is now irrelevant as a check is there to make sure that there's time left before approving the answer.

**Proof of concept**

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton"),
  testButton = document.getElementById("testButton"),
  resetButton = document.getElementById("resetButton"),
  timerEl = document.getElementById('timer'),
  timeLimit = 10, // in seconds
  startTime,
  timeId;

startButton.addEventListener("click", startTimer);
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reset);
testButton.addEventListener("click", promptUser);

function startTimer() {
  if (timeId) return;
  timerEl.innerHTML = "0";
  timeId = window.setInterval(displayNumber, 500);
  startTime = new Date();
}

function reset() {
  window.clearInterval(timeId);
  timerEl.innerHTML = "-";
  timeId = null;
}

function getElapsed() {
  return (new Date() - startTime) / 1000;
}

function isTimesUp() {
  return getElapsed() >= timeLimit;
}

function timesUp() {
  reset();
  alert("time's up");
  // display score
}

function displayNumber() {
  var elapsed = getElapsed();
  timerEl.innerHTML = Math.floor(elapsed);
  if (elapsed >= timeLimit) {
    timesUp();
  }
}

function promptUser() {
  var input = window.prompt("What is the state");
  if (isTimesUp()) return timesUp();
  // else check if the answer is correct

}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="startButton">Start</button>
<button type="button" id="resetButton">Reset</button>
<button type="button" id="testButton">Test Answer</button>
<div>Timer: <span id="timer">-</span>
</div>
```

The downside is that the timer will look like it froze in the background but once the prompt closed, the timer will take back to where it would be if it never froze, skipping any number in between.

Also, you don't need to refresh the page to reset, you can handle everything in the scripts like a single-page app would.

## Better solution

A better way to make interactive application with JavaScript is to [avoid default browser dialog boxes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/106039/183033) (alert, prompt, et.).

From the [MDN documentation on `alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert):

> Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing
>   the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed.
>   For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a
>   dialog box (or modal window).

Instead use custom made modals, which can be stylized, like [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or [jQuery's Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). These types of JavaScript modal don't stop code execution, so the timer element would still be updated in the background.

Comment: Also, what would you recommend to reset the game? After answering the question correctly, the star disappears.

Comment: @MattBrodley add anything inside the `reset` function (see my example) to put the app back to its initial state. Values, element's content, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Input dialogs block thread execution and JavaScript runs on one thread thus when a dialog appears all executions are frozen until the dialog is dismissed. A way around this would be to put your dialogs on another thread so that once they are active it does not stop execution of other functions.

[Introducing HTML 5 Web Workers: Bringing Multi-threading to JavaScript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/introducing-html-5-web-workers-bringing-multi-threading-to-javascript.html#fbid=pq9ooZ7o9v0)

Another option would be to create a custom alert that does not block the thread. [Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) is a good example of this.

Comment: While I mostly agree with you on using something else for a modal, **Toastr is**, as the name implies, **a toast notification lib**. It's not really suited for full blown modal dialog boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HTML5 Web Worker](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp).

Workers are in the background of a page, and you can interact with the page while they go, so make the timer a worker.

I don't use these very often, but I think it would be something like this:

```
var w = new Worker("the_name_of_your_timer.js");
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a timer to the alert box? So when the question appears the timer begins.

Comment: But the main thread won't be processing messages from the worker while the alert box is up.